# VS 2017 mouse navigate backward stopped working with ReSharper

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, resharper

I like the VS feature to navigate backwards (e.g. after Ctrl+Click) using mouse back button. Unfortunately this feature stopped working. Literally using mouse back button does nothing. I have found out that navigation works again when I disable ReSharper. However, with enabled ReSharper it does not. Does anyone meet the same issues? I am using ReSharper 2017.2.2 and VS 2017 15.4.4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft introduced its own `Ctrl+Click` feature implementation in the latest build of VS2017, try disabling it here `Tools | Options | TExt Editor | General | Untick "Enable mouse click to perform Go to Definition"` ckeckbox to get the correct behaviour back.

Comment: Simply untick the checkbox didn't work for me. I had to disable "Ctrl+Click Go To Definition" extension