# How to map View.NavigateBackward and Forward to mouse buttons in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2017

I'm having issues getting my mouse buttons to work with VS2017. I recently upgraded my dev machine to Win10 and have not been able to resolve this issue.
I'v tried the suggestions in: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686901/how-do-i-edit-visual-studios-mouse-shortcuts) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47329192/vs-2017-mouse-navigate-backward-stopped-working-with-resharper) to no avail.

The extension does not work nor does disabling the ctrl+click navigation.
The way I would like to use the navigation features is ctrl+click to go to definition and then mouse back button to return, or mouse forward to go forward, etc...

Any assistance would be appreciated.
Thanks